Camunda with Spring boot: Error creating bean with name 'camundaIntegrationDeterminator'
I am facing an issue with my spring app start up.
My pom has dependenies:
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-bom</artifactId>
        <version>7.22.0</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-engine-plugin-spin</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.connect</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-connect-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.connect</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-connect-http-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-engine-plugin-connect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.spin</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-spin-dataformat-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

My .bpmn is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:zeebe="http://camunda.org/schema/zeebe/1.0" xmlns:modeler="http://camunda.org/schema/modeler/1.0" id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Web Modeler" exporterVersion="14b513a" modeler:executionPlatform="Camunda Cloud" modeler:executionPlatformVersion="8.6.0">
  <bpmn:process id="simple-process" name="simple process" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn:startEvent id="simple-start" name="simple-start">
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_0zks8a4</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:startEvent>
    <bpmn:serviceTask id="simple-service" name="simple service">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <zeebe:taskDefinition type="com.example.MqttProcessor" />
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_0zks8a4</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_110acef</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:serviceTask>
    <bpmn:endEvent id="simple-end" name="simple end">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_110acef</bpmn:incoming>
    </bpmn:endEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_110acef" sourceRef="simple-service" targetRef="simple-end" />
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_0zks8a4" sourceRef="simple-start" targetRef="simple-service" />
  </bpmn:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="simple-process">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_2" bpmnElement="simple-start">
        <dc:Bounds x="150" y="100" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="139" y="143" width="58" height="14" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_120429i_di" bpmnElement="simple-service">
        <dc:Bounds x="450" y="78" width="100" height="80" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_1agucci_di" bpmnElement="simple-end">
        <dc:Bounds x="722" y="100" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="713" y="143" width="54" height="14" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_110acef_di" bpmnElement="Flow_110acef">
        <di:waypoint x="550" y="118" />
        <di:waypoint x="722" y="118" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_0zks8a4_di" bpmnElement="Flow_0zks8a4">
        <di:waypoint x="186" y="118" />
        <di:waypoint x="450" y="118" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>

On start up, error is thrown:
* (Not recommended) Deactivate the enforceTTL config to disable this check | resource D:\work\code\icccworkflow\target\classes\simple.bpmn | line 3 | column 79
* One of the attributes 'class', 'delegateExpression', 'type', or 'expression' is mandatory on serviceTask. If you are using a connector, make sure theconnect process engine plugin is registered with the process engine. | resource D:\work\code\icccworkflow\target\classes\simple.bpmn | line 7 | column 65
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.EngineUtilLogger.exceptionDuringParsing(EngineUtilLogger.java:66) ~[camunda-engine-7.22.0.jar:7.22.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.xml.Parse.throwExceptionForErrors(Parse.java:240) ~[camunda-engine-7.22.0.jar:7.22.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParse.execute(BpmnParse.java:354) ~[camunda-engine-7.22.0.jar:7.22.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer.transformDefinitions(BpmnDeployer.java:106) ~[camunda-engine-7.22.0.jar:7.22.0]
    ....
    ....
2024-12-27T12:02:54.893+05:30  WARN 11156 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'camundaIntegrationDeterminator': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'processEngine': Error creating bean with name 'processEngineFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
2024-12-27T12:02:54.898+05:30  INFO 11156 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-12-27T12:02:54.925+05:30  INFO 11156 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-12-27T12:02:54.930+05:30  INFO 11156 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-12-27T12:02:54.955+05:30  INFO 11156 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-12-27T12:02:55.042+05:30 ERROR 11156 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'camundaIntegrationDeterminator': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'processEngine': Error creating bean with name 'processEngineFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]

What am I missing?
